# Remove item from MutableMap inside a MutableSet

Tags: android, kotlin

```
var chart_values: MutableSet<MutableMap.MutableEntry<String, Any>>? = mutableSetOf()
```

Printing chart_values:

```
[ground={}, 
ground_level={}, 
date_of_birth=1988-07-18T00:00Z]
```

I try to remove it with the below code

```
Activity.player.chart_values.remove('date_of_birth')
```

the above line shows up error without even running

```
Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter 
T should be mentioned in input types (argument types, 
receiver type or expected type). Try to specify it explicitly.
```

Comment: Note that modifying any element of a `MutableSet` while it's still in the `MutableSet` is likely to break things.  Is a `MutableSet` really what you want, and not, say, a `MutableList`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes Mutableset is needed across the project

Comment: if you get very strange bugs where elements aren't being found in the set when they're right there, this will be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*chart_values* is a `MutableSet` with elements of type `MutableMap.MutableEntry<String, Any>`
So you can only remove a `MutableMap.MapEntry` from it, not a key to an entry of a `MutableMap`

You can iterate over the `MutableMap.MapEntry` elements of the `MutableSet` using an [iterator](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-set/iterator.html) and then try to remove the map entry with the given key.

```
var chart_values: MutableSet<MutableMap.MutableEntry<String, Any>>? = mutableSetOf()

fun removeMapEntry(mapKey: String): Boolean {
    val iterator: MutableIterator<MutableMap.MutableEntry<String, Any>> = chart_values?.iterator() ?: return false
    iterator.forEach { 
        // it: MutableMap.MutableEntry<String, Any>
        if (mapKey == it.key){
            iterator.remove()
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: can you pls look this thread aswell? Based on the same things https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58214162/duplicate-mutableset-in-kotlin

Comment: another thread based on the same topic -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58221009/how-to-remove-item-of-mutablemap-from-mutableset-if-it-is-empty

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how `MutableMap.MutableEntry<String, Any>` works but I would have done it using `Pair`

```
var chart_values: MutableSet<Pair<String, Any>> = mutableSetOf()
chart_values.removeIf { it.first == "date_of_birth" }
```