# Duplicate MutableSet in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried to duplicate

```
var chart_values: MutableSet<MutableMap.MutableEntry<String, Any>>? = mutableSetOf()
```

Like the following code

```
val chartMap = player.chart_values
```

*player* is the object of class **Player** where *chart_values* are

Printing *chart_values*:

```
[ground={}, 
ground_level={}, 
date_of_birth=1988-07-18T00:00Z]
```

I am able to get the data in *chartMap* but when I try to remove item from it, *chart_values* data is also getting removed surprisingly

Any insight?

Comment: Your `chartMap` is just a reference to `chart_values` thus when modifying `chartMap` you directly modify `chart_values`.

Comment: @MarošŠeleng yes that's right when I think of it, so how do we duplicate it?

Comment: You haven't duplicated anything, you've just created a new reference to the same MutableSet. `val chartMap = mutableSetOf(player.chart_values)` should do, but I'm a little rusty on Kotlin.

Comment: @alex Not working, chartMap has to be of the same type as chart_values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `toMutableSet()` method to make a copy of the set.

```
val chartMap = player.chart_values.toMutableSet()
```