# How to remove an item from a MutableSet given a certain condition?

Tags: kotlin, collections

```
var chart_values: MutableSet<MutableMap.MutableEntry<String, Any>>? = mutableSetOf()
```

Printing *chart_values*:

```
[ground={}, 
ground_level={0=115, 1=4, 2=0, 3=37, 4=63, 5=44, 6=40, 7=9}, 
ground_over={0=3, 1=3, 2=3, 3=3, 4=3, 5=3, 6=3}
date_of_birth=1988-07-18T00:00Z]
```

I would like to `remove ground={}` from the *chart_values*

Comment: Why aren't you using a map or a set of pairs? Can your second generic type be a Collection instead of Any?

Comment: @Tenfour04 the second generic type can't be a collection because the key "date_of_birth" is associated with a date of some type.

Comment: @johnrao07 I removed the Android tag since your question is about pure Kotlin.

Comment: The line about the date was added after I commented.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `chartValues` is of type `MutableSet<MutableMap.MutableEntry<String, Any>>?` you can do the following to remove any entry with an empty map as a value:

```
chartValues?.removeAll { (_, value) ->
    (value as? Map<*,  *>)?.isEmpty() == true
}
```

`as?` is called safe cast operator and will return the casted object or null if the cast did not succeed.

Note:

- You might be better off using a `MutableMap<String, Any>`
- use `val` instead of `var`, since you want to mutate the collection an not the reference to it

Comment: "ground" is just one item in the map, I am looking to remove empty maps. I did it manually and it is working for me

Comment: @johnrao07 ahh ok, i missed that. see my updated answer.

Comment: The value associated with `ground` seems to be a `Map`, because it is printed as `{}`. Thus, the predicate should be `(value as? Map<*, *>)?.isEmpty() == true`

Comment: @johnrao07 does that answer your question?

Comment: @WilliMentzel I did it manually and its working, maybe I will refactor the code using your code after I am done with the project and update it then

Answer (score 0):

BTW:

- Your set can be actually a map `Map<String, Any>`
- `chart_values` doesnt comply with kotlins naming convetions. Use camel case

Since the value is of type `Any` - which should be changes to more specific type if possible - we have to check for instance first

```
val chart_values: MutableSet<MutableMap.MutableEntry<String, Any>>? = mutableSetOf()
val withoutEmptyValues = chart_values.filter { (_, value) -> value is Collection<*> && value.isNotEmpty() }
```

EDIT

If some elements are no collections:

```
val withoutEmptyValues = chart_values.filter { (_, value) -> if(value is Collection<*>) value.isNotEmpty() else true }
```

**Test**

I can't create instances of `MutableMap.MutableEntry`, so I created a mao which does it for me internally:

```
    val map: MutableMap<String, Any> = mutableMapOf(
            "ground" to listOf<Int>(1, 2, 3),
            "empty" to emptyList<Double>(),
            "date" to "1988-07-18T00:00Z"
    )

    val withoutEmptyValues = map
            .filter { (_, value) -> if (value is Collection<*>) value.isNotEmpty() else true }

    assertThat(withoutEmptyValues).isNotEmpty.isEqualTo(
            mutableMapOf<String, Any>(
                    "ground" to listOf<Int>(1, 2, 3),
                    "date" to "1988-07-18T00:00Z"
            )
    )
```

Comment: Edited the chart_values, your edit works with my edited values? I will test your code in a minute

Comment: My tests tell me otherwise. I don't know how you get your input or how you copy/pasted - please check again, since I'm 100% sure it solves your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun removeMapEntryIfEmpty() {
        val iterator: MutableIterator<MutableMap.MutableEntry<String, Any>> =
            player.chart_values?.iterator()!!
        iterator.forEach {
            // it: MutableMap.MutableEntry<String, Any>

            if (it.value.toString() == "{}") {
                iterator.remove()

            }
        }
    }
```